# How are matrices stored in Matlab/Octave?

Tags: arrays, matlab, numpy, matrix, octave

#### Short version

If I have matrix like this:

```
1  2
3  4
```

In memory, is it stored as `[1 2 3 4]` or as `[1 3 2 4]`. In other words, are matrices **more optimized** for **row** or for **column access**?

---

#### Long version

I'm translating some code from Matlab to NumPy. I'm used to C convention for multidimensional arrays (i.e. last index veries most rapidly, matrices are stored by rows) which is [default for NumPy arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.html#multidimensional-array-indexing-order-issues). However, in Matlab code I see snippets like this all the time (for arrangement several colored images in a single multidimensional array):

```
images(:, :, :, i) = im
```

which looks suboptimal for C convention and more optimized for FORTRAN convention (first index veries most rapidly, matrices are stored by columns). So, is it correct that Matlab uses this second style and is better optimized for column operations?

Comment: If you're asking about optimisation for speed, the only way to know for sure is to measure different methods on *your system* and see which one is fastest.

Comment: @GregHewgill: as I outlined below, I made a couple of simple tests, but got almost no difference. And complicated examples depend on too many things to actually compare performance of basic operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: It is stored column-wise.

```
A = [1 2; 3 4];
A(:) = [1; 3; 2; 4];
```

In many cases, the performance can be much better if you do the calculations in the "correct order", and operate on full columns, and not rows.

A quick example:

```
%% Columns
a = rand(n);
b = zeros(n,1);
tic
for ii = 1:n
  b = b + a(:,ii);
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.252358 seconds.

%% Rows:
a = rand(n);
b = zeros(1,n);
tic
for ii = 1:n
  b = b + a(ii,:);
end
toc
Elapsed time is 2.593381 seconds.
```

More than 10 times as fast when working on columns!

Comment: Incredible! I made several simple tests using vectorization and column-wise writes, but results were almost the same. I definitely didn't expect 10x speedup. Is it all about CPU (when entire column/memory line is read into a cache) or Matlab has other special optimizations? Anyway, thanks for object lesson!

Comment: @ffriend: See Locality of Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference#Matrix_multiplication

Answer (score -1):

```
%% Columns
n = 4000;

a = rand(n);
b = zeros(n,1);
tic
for j = 1 : 10
 for ii = 1:n
  b = b + a(:,ii);
 end
end
toc


%% Rows new:
a = rand(n);
b = zeros(1,n);
tic
for j = 1 : 10
 for ii = 1:n
  b = b + a(ii);
 end
end
toc

%% Rows old:
a = rand(n);
b = zeros(1,n);
tic
for j = 1 : 10
 for ii = 1:n
  b = b + a(ii,:);
 end
end
toc
```

Results:

Elapsed time is 1.53509 seconds.

Elapsed time is 1.03306 seconds.

Elapsed time is 3.4732 seconds.

So it looks like working on rows is SLIGHTLY faster than working on column, but using **:** causes the slowdown.

Comment: The 'Rows new' benchmark and the conclusion is wrong: `a(ii)` is not the ii-th row but the ii-th element using linear indexing (unlike numpy).